# Getting the Rolling Average

Tags: sql, ingres

I have a list of Dates which appear in a dropdown box, I need to get the 12 month rolling average for each month. The list of dates are in the column called date_end.

```
SELECT total_subs, cust_region, cust_phone, date_end
FROM table_customer
where date_end >=  date_end - '13 months'
```

date_end is saved as an Ansidate.

```
date_end    
2014-08-31
2014-07-31
2014-06-30
2014-05-30
```

When a user selects a value from the dropdown list of end dates the query should return the chosen values between that end date and the end date minus 13 months

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The 13 months is working.

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate the data types for the columns mentioned in your query and to include some sample data. And - rolling average of what column? Thanks.

Comment: getting the rolling average of total_subs which is an integer, grouping by the region, phone number and date_end

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this in Ingres?  Forgive me if not.

```
SELECT total_subs, cust_region, cust_phone, date_end, (
    (select avg(total_subs)
     from table_customer tc2
     where tc2.date_end > tc.date_end - '12 months'
    ) as rolling_average
FROM table_customer tc
where date_end >=  date_end - '13 months'
```